# where is the vptr (virtual pointer) initialized in a class having only parameterized constructors?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, vptr

Suppose I have a class like this

```
class Base
{
    private:
        int i;
        int j;
    public:
        Base(int i)
        {
            this->i = i;
            j = 0;
        }
        Base(int i, int j)
        {
            this->i = i;
            this->j = j;
        }
        virtual void f()
        {
            cout<<"in base f()"<<endl;
        }
};
```

VPTR gets initialized in the beginning of the constructor. But in this case there is no default constructor, only 2 parameterized constructors. Where will the VPTR be initialized?

Comment: Why do you assign some special importance to *default* constructor? All constructors initialize vptr in exactly the same way. There's nothing special about the default one in this respect.

Comment: @AndreyT: It didn't strike my mind that all constructors will initialize vptr. Later, after seeing the answers, my doubt is cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Where is the vptr (virtual pointer) initialized in a class having only parameterized constructors?**

To be strictly technical this is completely implementation defined.
However, almost known compilers implement dynamic dispatch through vptr and v-table mechanism. All of these compilers will initialize the vptr to point to its own v-table in **each constructor's member initialization list**.

Something like:

```
Base::Base(...arbitrary params...)
   : __vptr(&Base::__vtable[0])  ← supplied by the compiler, hidden from the programmer
 {

 }
```

**[This](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.4)** C++ FAQ explains a gist of what exactly happens.

Answer (score 3):

Every constructor will first initialize the `vptr` pseudo-field. You can imagine that it is the first hidden field of every C++ class having some `virtual` member functions.

<sup>It is in theory possible to implement virtual functions without a virtual table pointer, but I know no common C++ implementation doing that.</sup>